# installing c# setup with same version

Tags: c#, winforms

I want basic information about windows installer. I made installer that has version 1.0.0.0. I installs this on your pc. Now I add new features to app and build setup(in debug from date I know its updated) and give it to you(its still 1.0.0.0). you uninstall old one and install this one. I have question here, what would be the impact ?

Actually case is that, I gave build 1.0.0 to my friend, he install this. I make UI and some logical changes in Form1(c#), build the setup(its new but still 1.0.0) and give it to him. he uninstall old one and installs this one. when program executed it shows new UI changes but my friend is asking that UI changed but not logic changed. I cant understand as its not logical argument that if UI updated of setup but not logic.

Can someone give valid argument ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're going to be hard pressed convincing your friend that he has a new version, given that the product version has not changed.  How can you confirm that he actually uninstalled the old version, or even installed the new version (and not have just run the old installer by mistake).

I think you have two options:

1. Update the product version of the installer, so that you can prove that a new version has been installed.  This could just be a minor or revision version change (e.g. 1.0.0.1)
2. Set the version of the .NET assemblies.  If you change these with each build, even if your installer version remains the same, you can verify that he has the new assemblies.

Comment: I know how to change it but I have to convince him. How do I know, its new? As I write in question I added new UI in new build and its showing new GUI as old build has not this GUI